# In source code, is it more secure to use several MySQL users that have limited access as opposed to using one user that can access everything?

Tags: mysql, security

I have a Perl website back-end that connects to MySQL databases. We have dozens of customers and each customer has their own database. So depending on which customer webpage we're on, the Perl will connect to a specific database using a MySQL user that only has access to that database. For example, MySQL user `customer1` only has access to database `customer1` and MySQL user `customer2` only has access to database `customer2`, etc.

Is that a common practice to make things more secure, or would it be just as secure to always use the same MySQL user that has access to all databases?

Comment: Some people implement security in the application; some do it via mysql logins; either has benefits and drawbacks.

Comment: If you're not doing it with mysql logins, then what do you have to do or protect against in the app/code?

Comment: You write the APP; they interact only with the APP.  They never write SQL; the APP generates SQL from their inputs.  Security is now on your shoulders.

Comment: anything besides SQL injection?

Comment: The APP needs to check for proper input and filter out things that could be SQL injection.  The APP needs to let the user see only the subset of data that the APP deems proper.

Comment: Your "customer" will be tagged by an id (_not_ exposed in any url) that indirectly controls the database the APP connects to.  One way to do this is with cookies.  Another is with "session" parameters.

Comment: One technique has the customer_id exposed, _but_ looked up in a table to verify that some random code matches what the cookie says.

Comment: You need to list the possible security breeches.  We have discussed two.  There may be a dozen.  How sensitive is the data?